# Execute Dynamically Created Script src link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have a dynamically created a script tag with src="URL" Placed inside a DIV but it doesn't seems to execute

Example

```
var userid = getUrlParameter('user');

    var url1 = "http://tools.vpscash.nl/dating/promo/relatie/registratie_formulier/vps.js?p=286&
pi="+userid+"&whitelabel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.contactensite.nl&fheight=500&fwidth=450&hd_text=Binnen+1+minuut+inschrijven%3Cbr%3Eveilig%2C+anoniem+en+gratis!&cta_text=Nu+gratis+aanmelden&height=348&width=448&hd_bgcolor=D74C6D&hd_color=FFFFFF&background=F2F2F2&color=000000&cta_bgcolor1=2AAA00&cta_bgcolor2=198A00&cta_color=FFFFFF&cta_shadow=75D660&border=444444";
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', url1);
    document.getElementById('verified').appendChild(s);
alert("success");
```

I am including Userid in to the url then assigning the link to Script SRC
The script is added in to the DIV but it is not executed

But, When I place the Script on PageLoad by framing URL manually it works. 
Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tools.vpscash.nl/dating/promo/relatie/registratie_formulier/vps.js?p=286&pi=&whitelabel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.contactensite.nl&fheight=500&fwidth=450&hd_text=Binnen+1+minuut+inschrijven%3Cbr%3Eveilig%2C+anoniem+en+gratis!&cta_text=Nu+gratis+aanmelden&height=348&width=448&hd_bgcolor=D74C6D&hd_color=FFFFFF&background=F2F2F2&color=000000&cta_bgcolor1=2AAA00&cta_bgcolor2=198A00&cta_color=FFFFFF&cta_shadow=75D660&border=444444"> </script>
```

Comment: You should be using the [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method to load async javascript file.

Comment: Is the file set to be run on document.load or document.ready event? Check the starting of the file.

Comment: @magreenberg  can you pls helo me with a sample code?

Comment: @TareqMahmood  i dint mention any document.ready event just  calling an script src url on load

Answer (score 0):

Ajax example.

```
var url1 = "your_long_long_url_you_need_to_load";

$.getScript( url1, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

This will load the script for you. You do not need to create a document element and append it to the page. [Read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

instead of

```
         s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
         s.setAttribute('src', url1);

put this

         s.type = 'text/javascript';
         s.src = url1;
         document.body.appendChild(s);
```